# WiredTiger memory usage vs cache usage

Tags: mongodb, aws, wiredtiger

We have a sharded MongoDB cluster running on 3 `m4.large` AWS EC2 instances (8GB RAM each)
Our Data size is 1.2GB

We set the WiredTiger `CacheSizeGB` to 2GB

I can see on the mongodb monitoring

- Memory usage : 1.8GB
- Cache usage : 1.6GB

Does that mean that my wiredTiger is using almost 80% of its cache and I should add more?

What will happen if the cache usage become 2GB ? will `mongod` crash or it will try to free some cache ?

in `htop` I can see that `mongod` is using only `900MB`

here is db.stats

```
        "objects" : 2790835,
        "avgObjSize" : 437.06898473037637,
        "dataSize" : 1221403413,
        "storageSize" : 542928896,
        "numExtents" : 0,
        "indexes" : 1410,
        "indexSize" : 2697195520,
        "fileSize" : 0,
        "extentFreeList" : {
                "num" : 0,
                "totalSize" : 0
        },
```